# Forward ethernet packets in other network and back

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, wifi, ethernet

i have a networking problem i was hoping to get some answers here. So i have multiple raspberry pi that all have wifi connectivity and ethernet. All the PIs are connected to a network via wifi, and on ethernet to each other. what i need is this: if a raspberry has a problem with the wifi(no signal or smth) i want to send that package over the ethernet and another raspberry should pick up that package on ethernet and forward that on it's owm wifi interface further. Could anybody give me some hints on how this should be approached? Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: are you making progress?

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene did research yesterday to have a more complete picture of it, now i'm starting implementing it, will tell you how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to enable routing in each pi, using sysctl, then enable dynamic routing on each pi, be it ospf or rip does not matter in your case, but you'll have to stick with your choice with the other pis, otherwise you will need to do more complex configuration.
i strongly suggest that you try to set it up yourself by reading the man, you'll get a feeling of satisfaction when you do it, i'm sure.
edit 1 : each pi will be a router, having 2 interfaces,2 ethernet connected pis should belong to the same subnet of course.
edit 2: when a wifi link is down, a raspberry will use the ethernet, the next pi must use nat to translate the packets so they can reach the public network.
example : wlan0 is external, eth1 is internal

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

edit 3: Setting up ospf
first, install quagga on each router(pi)
edit /etc/quagga/daemons and replace no by yes in the lines zebra and ospf 
then do this

```
cd /etc/quagga
cp /usr/share/doc/quagga/examples/zebra.conf.sample .
mv zebra.conf.sample zebra.conf
```

do the same for ospfd.conf and vtysh.conf
let the fun begin : 
 here is an example on how to do it

```
vtysh
conf t
router ospf
network 10.0.1.0/24 area 1
network 192.168.1.0/24 area 1
end
```

Comment: This enables masquerading (dynamic source NAT) on a Rpi. It is also necessary to enable IPv4 forwarding or NAT won't work (sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward). In addition to that, each Rpi (except the one that does the NAT) should have as default gateway the address of the Rpi that does the NAT.

Comment: i prefer using sysctl to configure kernel parameters, plus some distros are prohibiting modifying any file in the /proc directory, mint for example.

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene is there any solution for not assigning each raspberry a static IP? i would like to have dhcp enabled so each time i connect a new raspberry to the network, the eth interface get a IP from the network. Could running a dhcp server on each raspberry work? couldn't be there any conflicts when connecting a new raspberry to the network?

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene could you give me a few hints on how to enable and configure ospf in each raspberry? i'm a bit stuck there